# MySQL 5.6 calculation with datatype time within function returns wrong value - but outside is ok

Tags: mysql, function, time

I use mySQL 5.6 on Windows 7 Pro x64 and have the following problem.

```
SELECT fee(100, '12:00:00');
```

returns 500,000 which is obviously not correct.

But

```
SELECT 100 * '12:00:00'/24;
```

returns the correct result which is 50.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fee;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fee(price INT, duration TIME)
    RETURNS DECIMAL(15,2)
    BEGIN
        RETURN price * duration/24;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Have you ever encountered this problem? What is the reason behind it?

Thanks for any hints for solving this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you explicitly cast '12:00:00' to TIME data type in the `SELECT 100 * cast('12:00:00' AS TIME)/24` (I cannot access sqlfiddle at the moment to figure it out myself)

Comment: It gives me `500,000.0000`. The problem seems to be the datatype TIME.

Comment: Try `RETURN price * duration/'24:00:00'` instead

Comment: The same as before `500,00.0000` - if I change 24 to time format within the function it throws even a syntax error.

Comment: Try working with the appropriate time functinos instead of aritmetic maths, is more stable

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that in `100 * '12:00:00'/24` expression `'12:00:00'` is evaluated as string, not as a time expression, and in `'12:00:00'/24` operation the string is converted to a number, so it is executed as 12/24, which gives the expected result.

However, when the fee() function is called,  `'12:00:00'` is passed to a parameter with TIME data type. In the `duration/24` operation duration is converted to integer first, then the division is executed. However, `select cast(cast('12:00:00' as time) as integer)` conversion yields 120000, not 12. 120000/24*100=500000 - this is the output received from the original function. According to mysql documentation on [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html):

> Be careful about assigning abbreviated values to a TIME column. MySQL
>   interprets abbreviated TIME values with colons as time of the day.
>   That is, '11:12' means '11:12:00', not '00:11:12'. **MySQL interprets
>   abbreviated values without colons using the assumption that the two
>   rightmost digits represent seconds (that is, as elapsed time rather
>   than as time of day)**. For example, you might think of '1112' and 1112
>   as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL
>   interprets them as '00:11:12' (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly,
>   '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

Although the documentation describes integer to time conversion, it is safe to assume that time to integer conversion works the same way. I would use `price * time_to_sec(duration)/86400` to get the right result.

Comment: 120000 / 24 * 100 = 500000 illuminati confirmed

Comment: MySLQ is "lenient" at the CLI; the hint at "type" and parsing looks right: `select 100 * '12Garbage'/24;` yields `50`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helps and comments.

@Shadow, @B98 – you are right. The problem has to do with converting `'12:00:00'` to its corresponding numeric value.
I searched a lot about how MySQL performs converting time to number in general, however I didn't find anything.

So I started a little bit experimenting on it and this is what I found out about it yet:

1. The `default datatype` in MySQL is `VARCHAR`, so every `value/"variable"` which has no `explicit datatype` its `datatype` is `VARCHAR(length of value/variable)` as you've correctly guessed, Shadow.
2. Converting `VARCHAR` to a `numeric datatype` works generally like this: take all digits from the left of the string up to the point you find a character except `0-9`. If immediately after the digits there is a dot “.”, take the dot as the decimal point and continue searching for decimal digits till the string ends or you find a character except `0-9`.
   So in short: take from the left of the string what matches the pattern `[0-9][.[0-9]]` and throw the rest of it away – as you mentioned it, B98. Examples: `'12:30:59' = 12; '12whatever30whatever59' = 12; '12.30.59' = 12.30; '12.30whatever' = 12.30`
3. However, converting `TIME` to a `numeric datatype` works a little bit different: First remove the colons then convert it to an integer. Exempels: `'12:00:00' = 120000; '12:30:59' = 123059`
4. Converting `DATETIME` to a `numeric datatype` works the same way as converting `TIME` to numeric, except here get the dashes in the date part, the space between date and time and the colons in the time part removed and then gets the whole string converted to an integer. Exempels: `'2015-12-24 12:59:59' = '20151224125959'`

Below you find a query which shows this behavior of MySQL.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS datetimeTypes;
CREATE VIEW datetimeTypes AS
    SELECT 
        '12:59:00.50' AS timeImplicit,
        CAST('12:59:00.50' AS TIME) AS timeExplicit,
        '12:59:00.50' / 1 AS timeImplicitDiv,
        CAST('12:59:00.50' AS TIME) / 1 AS timeExplicitDiv,
        '2015-12-24 12:59:59' AS datetimeImplicit,
        CAST('2015-12-24 12:59:59' AS DATETIME) AS datetimeExplicit,
        '2015-12-24 12:59:59' / 1 AS datetimeImplicitDiv,
        CAST('2015-12-24 12:59:59' AS DATETIME)/1 AS datetimeExplicitDiv;

SHOW FIELDS FROM datetimeTypes;
SELECT * FROM datetimeTypes;
```